# Angular7: Global Guard - CanDeactivate interface

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-router-guards, angular-guards, angular7-router

I am very new to Angular, and was unsuccessful in finding an answer to what I am searching for.

The problem I am facing right now is that all the global error messages are not disappearing when I switch to another route.

I tried to solve this problem by using the CanDeactivate interface.
This is my canDeactivate method:

```html
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('delete test');
    this.globalMessageService.remove(GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_ERROR);
    return of(true);
  }
```

This method is created in a Service called cms-page.guard.ts and by using this in specific pages, it seems to work just fine. Example if I use this in the "Courses" page:

```html
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'courses',
    canActivate: [CmsPageGuards],
    canDeactivate: [CmsPageGuards],
    data: { pageLabel: 'courses' },
    component: CoursesPageComponent
  }
];
```

Basically, what I did is apply the canDeactivate method on a specific page.
I was wondering if it is possible to create a Guard that applies globally the canDeactivate method, so it works for all pages when you change to another route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your goal is to handle global errors. You don't need to use canDeactivateGuard for the same. You can achieve this by ErrorHandler interface.

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
constructor() { }
      handleError(error) {  //override handleError method
     //handle all errors here 
         console.log('error')
         // IMPORTANT: Rethrow the error otherwise it gets swallowed
         throw error;
      } 
}
```

Now just we  need to tell angular to use GlobalErrorHandler instead of its default

```
@NgModule({


 declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler, 
      useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And for all components having declaration in app.module.ts, GlobalErrorHandler will be used.
Hope it helps you!